# Flask and openCV multiple POST request

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, flask

So I'm making an Flask application that turns on and off a camera in a Raspberry Pi. The server code is as shown:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response
import requests, json, ast
import cv2, time, pandas
import threading
# importing datetime class from datetime library 
from datetime import datetime


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def camera():
    from camera_opencv_class import videoCapture
    data=list(request.form.keys())[0]
    print(data)

    if data=="turnon":
        video_object=videoCapture()
        t_videoCapture=threading.Thread(target=video_object.show)
        t_videoCapture.start()
        for i in threading.enumerate():
            i.record=True
        return Response(status=200)
    elif data=="turnoff":
        for i in threading.enumerate():
            i.record=False
        return Response(status=200)
    return Response(status=200)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0',debug=True,port=8000)
```

And the camera_opencv_class code is shown:

```
import cv2
from datetime import datetime
import threading

class videoCapture:
    # Capturing video 
    def show(placeholder):
        video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        # Assigning our static_back to None 
        static_back = None
      
        # List when any moving object appear 
        motion_list = [ None, None ] 
      
        videoCapture_thread=threading.currentThread()
        while getattr(videoCapture_thread,"record",True):
            # Reading frame(image) from video 
            check, frame = video.read() 
      
            # Initializing motion = 0(no motion) 
            motion = 0
        
            gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        
            gray=cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(21,21),0)
        
            if static_back is None:
                static_back=gray
                continue
        
            diff_frame=cv2.absdiff(static_back,gray)
        
            thresh_frame=cv2.threshold(diff_frame,30,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
            thresh_frame=cv2.dilate(thresh_frame,None,iterations=2)
        
            (cnts,_)=cv2.findContours(thresh_frame.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        
            for contour in cnts:
                if cv2.contourArea(contour)<10000:
                    continue
                motion=1
                (x,y,w,h)=cv2.boundingRect(contour)
                cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),3)
      
            #  Displaying image in gray_scale 
            #cv2.imshow("Gray Frame", gray) 
      
            # Displaying the difference in currentframe to 
            # the staticframe(very first_frame) 
            #cv2.imshow("Difference Frame", diff_frame) 
      
            # Displaying the black and white image in which if 
            # intencity difference greater than 30 it will appear white 
            #cv2.imshow("Threshold Frame", thresh_frame) 
      
            # Displaying color frame with contour of motion of object 
            cv2.imshow("Color Frame", frame) 
      
            key = cv2.waitKey(1)
            #print("on")  
      
        video.release() 
      
        # Destroying all the windows 
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

So as you can see when I send a request to turn on the camera a thread will start to turn on the camera, and when I send a request to turnoff camera the thread's "record" property will be False and thus the thread will be ended. This works. However, when I again send a turn on request, a new thread was created however nothing happens; the camera does not turn on. Does anyone know why? Maybe it is something unique within openCV that does not allow me to do this? Or anyone knows a better way to do this task altogether? The server is forwarded using Ngrok and I do the requests using a separate computer (the main goal to do this using IFTTT from my phone)

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
t_video_capture.join()
```

before returning a response.